# How do i count descendant::w:p is more than one in <xsl:when> using xslt 2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I want to test one condition in `<xsl:when>`. The condition is  i want to test if the count of descendant::w:p is more than one then only it enters into the `<xsl:when>` for further processing.

How i do it?

Please guide me to get out of this issue using `<xsl:when>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The condition is i want to test if the count of `descendant::w:p` is
>   more than one then only it enters into the `<xsl:when>` for further
>   processing.

**In both XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0**:

```
<xsl:when test="descendant::w:p[2]">
  <!-- Processing here  -->
</xsl:when>
```

**Do note**: There is *no* guarantee that the instructions inside this particular `<xsl:when>` will be executed even when the expression in its `test` attribute evaluates to `true()`. In case another `<xsl:when>` that is a preceding-sibling of this one has its `test` satisfied, then its inside code will be selected for execution and any of its following `xsl:when` / `xsl:otherwise` siblings will not be evaluated.